# lwuit container

Tags: lwuit

I have added a container named `btnBar` with `boxlayout(x-axis)` on a form. the container has 4 buttons of custom class `MyButton` that extends from `Button` itself. When i add `actionlistener` to one of the buttons in the container it gets invoked for each n every button. Even the `actionevent.getsource.gettext` method returns the same value irrespective of the focus. I have added the buttons through an array and m trying to use is something like this:

```
btns[0].addActionListener(......)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

got is solved buddies...actually was using setfocus() to traverse within the btnBar on buttons...but needed to use setFocused() method of form too....after setFocus()....dnt hammer ur brains now....

Comment: You should accept this answer to remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You must never use `setFocus`, you should use `setFocusable` to toggle focusability and `requestFocus` to get the focus to a specific component.

You should also migrate to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/), since LWUIT is pretty much unmaintained.